# Why isn't my rep updating?

Tags: support, reputation

So far I've posted another question and an answer, someone accepted me answer and I've had up-votes.  How come my rep isn't updating here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Meta FAQ](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation):

> ### What is reputation?
>
> You must have at least 5 reputation on the main website to participate on Robotics Meta - Stack Exchange.
>
> Reputation here is entirely derived from the main website; your reputation is the same here as it is there, synchronized hourly. Votes here do not affect your reputation in any way. However, you can earn unique badges here on the meta site.

So only when you start getting votes on the main site will you reputation increase.

Comment: whoa, is this how it is on all SE sites? i did not know that, but it makes sense since you want people to be experts at robots and not at being a meta

Comment: @TMP - I think the only exception is the [first meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), which is kinda the *meta* meta site (the meta site for the whole stack exchange system) as well as the meta for stack overflow. *8')